# Elasticsearch 6.2 start a localhost http node in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, elasticsearch, junit, aws-elasticsearch

My goal is to start a localhost elasticsearch node in my junit test, so I can index some docs and also test search queries through high level rest client(e.g. making http calls to localhost ES node). I'm using Elasticsearch 6.2.

Here is the code I tried

```
    String clusterName = "test";
    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("path.home", ES_WORKING_DIR)
            .build();
    new Node(settings).start();
```

and this is the error message I got..

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported transport.type []

at __randomizedtesting.SeedInfo.seed([74752622FDACDD5:AB9FD863FD5A2A5F]:0)
at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkModule.getTransportSupplier(NetworkModule.java:212)
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:427)
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:246)
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:242)
```

Basically, I'm not sure what parameters to set in Settings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [embedded-elasticsearch](https://github.com/allegro/embedded-elasticsearch) library provides an easy way to start an Elasticsearch node in a separate process.

Comment: You can try docker

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263143/unsupported-http-type-netty3-when-trying-to-start-embedded-elasticsearch-node/41542097

Answer (score 2):

These are no longer supported by elastic, but they work for Junit test purposes

I have the following

For 5.6.7

```
Settings.Builder nodeSettings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", "my-integration-test")
            .put("http.enabled", "true")
            .put("path.data", dataDirectory)
            .put("path.home", "/")
            .put("transport.type", "netty4")
            .put("network.host", "_local_")
            .put("transport.tcp.port", "19200-19400")
            .put("http.port", "19200-19400")
            .put("discovery.type", "single-node");

    LOG.info("Starting up embedded Elasticsearch");
    node = new LocalNode(nodeSettings.build(), Arrays.asList(Netty4Plugin.class,
            ReindexPlugin.class));
    node.start();
```

For elastic 6.8.3

```
        Settings.Builder nodeSettings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", "integration-test")
            .put("node.name", "node-test")
            .put("path.data", dataDirectory)
            .put("path.home", "/")
            .put("transport.type", "netty4")
            .put("network.host", "127.0.0.1")
            .put("http.port", "19200");

    LOG.info("Starting up embedded Elasticsearch");
    node = new LocalNode(nodeSettings.build(), Arrays.asList(Netty4Plugin.class,
            ReindexPlugin.class,
            CommonAnalysisPlugin.class));

        node.start();
```

where

```
private static class LocalNode extends Node {

    LocalNode(Settings settings, Collection<Class<? extends Plugin>> classpathPlugins) {
        super(new Environment(settings, null), classpathPlugins, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerDerivedNodeNameWithLogger(final String s) {}

}
```

For 6.8.x you will need

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codelibs.elasticsearch.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>analysis-common</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What is LocalNode? It doesn't seem to be an elasticsearch type.

Comment: It's an `inner class` extending `Node`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263143/unsupported-http-type-netty3-when-trying-to-start-embedded-elasticsearch-node/41542097.

Comment: Hi, Where and what do I enter a transport for ES 7.16.3? I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported transport.type []`  - I installed Zulu 17 first on Windows

Comment: I have Zulu 11 and still have this same error.